# Why can't I debug my PHP code on docker with VS Code using Xdebug v3?

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I am trying to build a small environment to test PHP debugging in docker with Visual Studio Code. My idea is to create a model that I can use for the several PHP systems we have here at the company. However, I haven’t been able to debug or use breakpoints… It’s like VSCode is disconnected from Xdebug.

This is my Dokerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt upgrade -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mysqli pdo_mysql \
&& docker-php-ext-enable mysqli 
RUN pecl install xdebug-3.1.5 \
&& docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
ADD ./app /var/www/html
COPY ./app/test-form.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/test-form.conf

# Copy php.ini
COPY ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php

RUN echo 'SetEnv MYSQL_DB_CONNECTION ${MYSQL_DB_CONNECTION}' >> /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/environment.conf
RUN echo 'SetEnv MYSQL_DB_NAME ${MYSQL_DB_NAME}' >> /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/environment.conf
RUN echo 'SetEnv MYSQL_USER ${MYSQL_USER}' >> /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/environment.conf
RUN echo 'SetEnv MYSQL_PASSWORD ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}' >> /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/environment.conf
RUN echo 'SetEnv SITE_URL ${SITE_URL}' >> /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/environment.conf
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf &&\
    a2enmod rewrite &&\
    a2enmod headers &&\
    a2enmod rewrite &&\
    a2dissite 000-default &&\
    a2ensite test-form &&\
    service apache2 restart
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "1"
services:
  webserver:
    image: form-test
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      # - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DB_CONNECTION: test
      MYSQL_DB_NAME: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      SITE_URL: http://localhost
      XDEBUG_MODE: develop,debug
      XDEBUG_CONFIG:
        client_host=host.docker.internal
        start_with_request=yes
networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge
```

This is my xdebug_info.php

```php
<?php

// xdebug_info();

phpinfo();
```

This is my php.ini

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
```

This is my launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen on Docker for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "hostname": "0.0.0.0"
        },    
    ]
}
```

Now this is weird… seems that Xdebug is successfully connecting to VSCode because when I launch my `xdebug_info.php` it shows this message:

[image]

When I start listening on VSCode, the message disappear:

[image]

I also noticed that the blue bottom bar in VS Code doesn't turn orange like it should. After building up my environment and not being able to make it work.

Comment: Try to add stop on entry to launch.json. Probably a path mapping issue. What is the path of the script inside and outside of docker?

Comment: Out of the original question, why do you use `docker-compose` version 1?

Comment: Also, in php.ini, you are mixing Xdebug2 and Xdebug3 settings. However the ones in the docker Env are taking effect so that is not the issue. Also try adding xdebug_break() into your code.

Comment: You are exposing port 443 from docker, but not 9003 (where xdebug is listening)

Comment: @symcbean *"You are exposing port 443 from docker, but not 9003 (where xdebug is listening)"* WRONG. It's Xdebug that connects to the debug client (VSCode in this case) and NOT other way around. Check the manual first please.

Comment: *"Now this is weird… seems that Xdebug is successfully connecting to VSCode because when I launch my xdebug_info.php it shows this message:"* This means that VSCode is NOT listening on Xdebug port yet or the connection is blocked by something (e.g. firewall) or the wrong address/IP is used. Once again -- it's Xdebug that that connects to the debug client and not other way around.

Comment: *"When I start listening on VSCode, the message disappear:"* And now Xdebug was able to connect (once you have told VSCode to start listing for connections). Try this simple script and see how it will do: `<?php $a = 1; $b = 3; $c = $a + $b;  echo $c;` Place each command on a separate line, put breakpoint on `$a = ` line and try from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Xdebug is alreday connecting to vscode and starts a debugging session. So the [comment by zobo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77237961/why-cant-i-debug-my-php-code-on-docker-with-vs-code-using-xdebug-v3#comment136165545_77237961) is probably right: it is just a path mapping issue.

And indeed, in your `docker-compose.yml` you are bind mounting

```yaml
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
```

but in your `launch.json` config you have

```json
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
```

So - assuming `docker-compose.yml` is in the root folder, which is also the workspace folder for vscode - you actually need to map

```json
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}/app"
            },
```

Comment: You the man! That was exactly right. I added /app to the mapping and now it is working like charm. Thank you so much!